# What does the Y coordinate define when calling Canvas​Rendering​Context2D.fill​Text?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am looking at [this page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText).

In the syntax section it says:

> y ... The y-axis coordinate of the point at which to begin drawing the text, in pixels.

I copied their example from the page and set `y` to `0`:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.font = '50px serif';
ctx.fillText('Hello world', 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="150" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

As you can see when running the snippet, nothing is visible on the canvas. So `x` does define the left coordinate, but `y` does not define the top coordinate for drawing the text. What does `y` define? Is it the baseline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At coordinates `(0,0)`, the canvas draws the text with the default baseline of alphabetic i. e line on top of which characters are drawn.

The position of the baseline can be controlled by below properties as per MDN:

[image: MDN baseline settings]

Sample working code for expected result with baseline `hanging`:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.textBaseline = 'hanging';
ctx.font = '50px serif';
ctx.fillText('Hello world', 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="150" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/abbNJVr

Answer (score 1):

```
What does y define?
```

The y-axis coordinate of the point at which to begin drawing the text, in pixels. This means the y-axis coordinate should be greater than. If you define this like 0 or negative value then canvas becomes `invisible`.

Just take the example as you have a simple paper with the coordinated and only positive coordinate of the y-axis is visible to you so, whatever written in the negative or 0 y-axes, it never becomes visible.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.font = '50px serif';
ctx.fillText('Hello world', 0, 40);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="150" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Comment: What does "relative to the canvas" mean? Why 40?

Comment: It defines y-axis in pixels. I have added the 40 to make the complete text visible. You can change it to anything but make sure that this is the value in pixel which is the most important thing in this point

Comment: I think that y defines the position of the baseline on which the text is drawn. If you change the "d" of "world" to a "p", you can see a part of the "p" which is below the baseline even if you specify 0 for y.